# Handling multiple distribution methods with a git repo

Tags: git

I've been co-working on a browser puzzle based game using `html`, `js` and `css`, and it uses `git` for source control.
You can run the game using `index.html` of coarse and will be hosted on a server soon.

Lately I've been thinking about creating a [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) version/package of the project so I can distribute it on the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps) too. And will consider other markets soon.
This will require some additional files to be added to the git repo, which are specific to a `chrome-app` version of the repo.
Along with some minor code changes to allow full integration within `Chrome`.

Would it be better to create a fork of my original repo and handle those `chrome-app` files there. So the original/plain game is separate from the `chrome-app` port?
Or considering the minor code changes required, would a totally separate git repo be better and manually copy updates between repos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few ways to go about managing product lines, depending on your comfort level with managing repos, branches, tags etc.

One way is to create a new `chrome-app` repo, and introduce your original (maybe call it something like `baseline`) repo as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in your `chrome-app` repo. So if you are using github, you can do something like:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/<username>/<baseline>.git
```

If you decided to use submodules, you should familiarize yourself with [commands like `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Then you can use `git merge` and `git fetch` to merge in new changes from your upstream `baseline` repo, and `git push --recurse-submodules` to publish changes back to your `baseline`.

Alternately, if you felt this is an overkill, you can just fork from your original repo, to create a `chrome-app` repo. Since you are the owners of these repos, it should be easy for your to sync them using [`git push`](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/) and [`git pull`](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork/).

And if even that is too much, (for small projects) you can just branch off the `master` of your original repo, and keep everything in one repo.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely better handled in a build system than in a source control system.  Either put all these resources (for all the distribution methods) in sub-folders, or create a git repository for each distribution method, and use sub-modules to pull in the game code.  Copying and pasting code between repositories is a very bad idea.